# Looping through a JOIN'ed MySQL Associative Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, while-loop

Right, so I've got a query that looks like this:

```
$bestof_query = "SELECT * FROM physicians p JOIN (awards a, categories c, awardLevels l) ON (a.id = p.id AND c.id = a.category AND l.id = a.level) ORDER BY a.category, a.level ASC ";
$query = mysql_query($bestof_query);

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
 extract($result);
 echo "<h3>" . $category . "<h3>";
   foreach($category as $value) {
       echo "<h5>" . $name . "<h5>" . "<p>" . $description . "</p>" . "\r\n";
   }
}
```

A typical result looks like-

```
Array (
 [0] => 39  [id] => 1
 [1] => William�B.�Poff [name] => William�B.�Poff
 [2] => 10 South Main Street [address1] => 10 South Main Street
 [3] => Tower A, Suite 1400 [address2] => Tower A, Suite 1400 
 [4] => Jackson [city] => Jackson 
 [5] => VA [state] => VA
 [6] => 24111 [zip] => 24111
 [7] => downtown-jackson [neighborhood] => downtown-jackson
 [8] => 5409837649 [phone] => 5401111111
 [9] => http://www.foo.com [uri] => http://www.foo.com 
 [10] => Foo�Rogers,�PLC [firm] => Foo�Rogers,�PLC
 [11] => 39 
 [12] => 1 [category] => Bankruptcy
 [13] => 1 [level] => 1 
 [14] => 2009 [year] => 2009 
 [15] => 1 
 [16] => Bankruptcy 
 [17] => 1 
 [18] => Platinum [description] => Platinum )
```

I'm trying to loop through based on the [category] and while the category is equal to Bankruptcy, then output all the results for bankruptcy, then move on to the next category.

Does that make sense?  I've never been very good with loops so thanks in advance!

What I am hoping for is-

```
<h3>$category</h3>
<ul>
<li>$name - $description</li>
<li>$name - $description</li>
<li>$name - $description</li>
<li>$name - $description</li>
</ul>
```

And then iterate to the next category.  I think a nested loop, but I'm not sure how to do the nested loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple state machine. This is a way of doing a nested loop without doing a real nested loop. Especially as the data-stream is a single-dimension.

```
$category = '';
while( $result = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
    if( $result['category'] != $category ) {
        $category = $result['category'];
        echo "<h3>".$category."</h3>\n";
    }

    echo "<h5>".$result['name']."</h5>\n";
    echo "<p>".$result['description']."</p>\n";
}
```

It gets more complex if you have markup for each group as a whole, but this is the basic idea. It relies on the fact that that everything in the same category is together, which you achieve with the `ORDER BY`.

P.S: don't use `extract()`; it pollutes your namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the assistance.  I'll keep the advice in mind on extract().  It's convenient though but I get what you're saying, especially when dealing with multiple result sets I guess right?

Comment: What if I wanted to wrap the results (not the conditional if output) in a <div>?  Like directly before the <h3> I could put the opening <div> but how would I handle the </div>?

Comment: You extend the state-machine a bit. You can easily close a <div> just before you open the next one, but then you have to remember two things: to close the last one at the end of the loop and to open a 'dummy' one at the start of the loop. You can do tricks with variables that cut down on that, if you like.

Comment: The other major alteration to this type of loop is to shift the termination check into the middle of the loop. It is not obvious how to do this in this example, I'm afraid. But once you start duplicating code, remember this possibility because it will then provide a very elegant solution to part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM physicians p JOIN (awards a, categories c, awardLevels l) ON (a.id = p.id AND c.id = a.category AND l.id = a.level) ORDER BY a.category, a.level ASC ";
$query = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) { 
      $categories[$row['category']][] = $row;
}

foreach($categories as $key=>$value){
    echo"<h3>$key</h3>\r\n";
    echo "<div><ul>\r\n";
    foreach($value as $physician){
    echo "  <li>".$physician['name']." - ".$physician['description']."</li>\r\n";
    }
    echo "</ul></div>\r\n"
}
```

Comment: I've never used GROUP BY .. but in a quick test I don't think I'm using it right because instead of getting 200+ results as before now I'm only getting 37.  I tried this:

SELECT * FROM physicians p JOIN (awards a, categories c, awardLevels l) ON (a.id = p.id AND c.id = a.category AND l.id = a.level) GROUP BY a.category

Comment: Isn't that what I was already doing with: "ORDER BY a.category, a.level ASC" ?  My question is how to accomplish the loop, I think I've got the MySQL right or no?

Comment: well that's outputting everything yes, but I think I need a nested loop so I can output the category, then loop the names in that category, then move to the next category.  I'll edit the original post to show what I mean.

Comment: hmm...that's not working, it's outputting: <ul> 
  <li>3 - 3</li> 
  <li>R - R</li> 
  <li>1 - 1</li> 
  <li>S - S</li> 
  <li>R - R</li> 
  <li>V - V</li> 
  <li>2 - 2</li> 
  <li>o - o</li> 
  <li>2 - 2</li> 
  <li>U - U</li> 
  <li> - </li> 
  <li>U - U</li> 
  <li>3 - 3</li> 
  <li>2 - 2</li> 
  <li>S - S</li> 
</ul>

Comment: can you show me 
    print_r($categories);
before the foreach loop

Comment: yup-  Array ( [] => Array ( [id] => 3 [physicianName] => Robert A. Whisnant [address1] => 102 HIGHLAND AVENUE, SE [address2] => SUITE 105 [city] => Roanoke [state] => VA [zip] => 24013 [neighborhood] => old-southwest [phone] => 2147483647 [officeName] => Urology Associates, LTD [URI] => [category] => Urology [level] => 3 [year] => 2009 [description] => Silver ) )

Comment: changed categories to category in the while loop

Comment: heh, we're getting there..it's outputting the categories correctly but the list items are still only the first character?  ie:  <h3>Pediatrics</h3> 
<ul> 
  <li>3 - 3</li> 
  <li>M - M</li> 
  <li>4 - 4</li> 
  <li> - </li> 
  <li>R - R</li> 
  <li>V - V</li> 
  <li>2 - 2</li> 
  <li>s - s</li> 
  <li>2 - 2</li> 
  <li>C - C</li> 
  <li>h - h</li> 
  <li>P - P</li> 
  <li>3 - 3</li> 
  <li>2 - 2</li> 
  <li>S - S</li> 
</ul>

Comment: The other thing I'm noticing is the loop is only outputting one of the values from each category.  For example, the Allergy/Immunology category has 3 rows, but only one is showing up in the print_r.  It's the same for all of them.

Comment: Props for the try, but @staticsan below got it.  Thanks!

Comment: ok i found the mistake I was replace the item in the categories array rather than adding a new row to each category thats why you were only get one I made an edit it should would as expect, I know you found a solution but could you try it out for me so I can rest in that I have it right ?